# Check if start datetime and end datetime are valid in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Im new to momentJs so I need a bit of help here. I am building a form where the user can send in their availabilities for a certain work period. So in the form you have a startDate, startTime, endDate and endTime. Due to the api that I have to use from a client we have to send the date like this (example) "2015-06-17T14:24:36" (with the 'T' in the middle). Currently I receive the date and the time seperate from eachother but merging them together in the end so it fits the api's way of reading date.

Now my question is as follow. I have to create a check where I can see if the input startdate-time and enddate-time are valid. For example the startdate always has to be a date BEFORE the end date (pretty logic right). But is there an easy way to do this in momentJS?

Or should I use another method?

Thanks in regard and if my question is not quite clear please let me know so I can provide extra information!

NOTE: in the end it should be something like this:

var start = "2017-06-17T14:24:36"

var end = "2017-07-03T14:24:36"

***Function that checks if the start and end dates are valid***

Result = true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply have to check that `startDate` is before `endDate` you can use [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/).

Here a working sample:

```js
var start = "2017-06-17T14:24:36";
var end = "2017-07-03T14:24:36";

function checkDate(start, end){
 var mStart = moment(start);
 var mEnd = moment(end);
 return mStart.isBefore(mEnd);
}

console.log(checkDate(start, end));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

In my first example I'm using [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parsing that accepts input in ISO 8601 format.

If you need to parse non ISO 8601 format you can use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) specifying input format (e.g. `var mStart = moment(start, 'DD-MM-YYYYTHH:mm:ss');`).

If you have to support multiple formats you can use [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/). As docs states `moment(String, String[])`:

> - Prefer formats resulting in valid dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later.

Comment: Yes! This was exacly what I was looking for! Just a little question extra.. is it also possible to switch the YYYY-MM-DD format to DD-MM-YYYY in the same string? Or will moment js not recognize this?

Comment: @TomLuijten do you mean that you have to accept both `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` and `DD-MM-YYYYTHH:mm:ss`?

Comment: I mean that our client has a habit of changing things every now and then so now he is using a YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format but it might change to DD-MM-YYYYThh:mm:ss eventually I only use one of the two options but I was just wondering if moment could also use the other way of the date format :)

Comment: @TomLuijten ok so you can use `moment(start)` as shown in the snippet since date string is in ISO 8601 format and use moment [parsing with format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) if you need to support other formats, as I stated in the second part of my answer. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if It solved your issue (you also get reputation for that).